# Why don't any of the files on my Android tablet show up on my computer when I connect my computer with my Android tablet through USB?

Tags: usb, storage, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

The computer (Windows 7) recognizes the tablet but I can't see anything when I click on the "drive" corresponding to the tablet.

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad tablet.

Comment: have you put it into "USB mode" or something of the like? Most Android devices require you to enable a mode that allows the attached system to view the files on the device.

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll over to"?

Comment: Okay - I should look USB mode up and see how that goes. I just edited "scroll over to" out and replaced it with something more descriptive.

Comment: Now that I'm looking again, "Transfer files (Media Transfer Protocol)" is selected under USB Settings, and "Allow sync with PC" is selected under "Accounts & Sync" settings.